# How can I make a practical DD-MM form input?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm creating an application in Django and in the registration I'd like users to enter the day and month they were born, so that their birthday can be hailed on the site. I can't really think of a practical way to do this, I'm having trouble converting the jQuery datepicker to MM-DD format and the other method I have made (that works decently) is impractical and throws an error:

Here's what I have done, which I want to change:

```
<script>
    const daysInMonth = (month, year) => {
                return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
            }
    
            $('#birthday_year').change(function(){
                verifyDate(daysInMonth)
                $('#birthday_month').change(function(){
                    daysInMonth = daysInMonth($('#birthday_month').val(), $('#birthday_year').val())
                    verifyDate(daysInMonth);
                    $('#birthday_day').change(function(){
                        verifyDate(daysInMonth);
                    })
                })
            })
    
            const verifyDate = () => {
                if($('#birthday_day').val() > daysInMonth){
                            $('#birthday_day').val('Select an option');
                }
            }
     </script>
```

I won't show the form code, but it takes 3 inputs - Year of birth; month of birth and day of birth. The actual issue is that I cannot efficiently moderate the day people enter, basically I can't check whether a day is in the month they enter. E.g. someone could enter febuary 31st as their birthday.

I'm open to suggestions on a better way to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Marcono1234 it's javascript mate

Comment: Ahh I made a typo, sorry friend